# Facebook Login - dialog/oauth giving error

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

When I try to access my Facebook app without being logged into Facebook, I'm getting an error. If I'm already logged into Facebook, I get directed to the application normally, but without being logged in

Using the example for server-side CSRF on [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), my site generates a "state" variable to store in the session and redirects the user to the following URL:

> http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[APP_ID]&redirect_uri=[APP_URL]&state=[RANDOM_NUMBER]

All I'm getting by way of an error message is

> **Error**
>
> An error occurred. Please try later.

With no clear indication what's gone wrong, where, or why.

The app is running on a live server, with the domain name and path matching what's specified in the Facebook app control panel.

Answer (score 0):

If your receiving the Error 'An error occurred. Please try later.' on the Facebook login page then i would suggest you to verify the value for the parameter 'redirect_uri'. the value supplied in the above url should match with the one set for the facebook app in the spp settings page.

Had faced a similar problem during my initial days. Hope this helps.